Flatten values retrieved from any level of a JSON object
I have JSON objects that contain double values under the key value. However, sometimes those are nested, so data structures like this can exist:
[
    {
      "value": 0.1
    },
    {
      "value": {
        "value": 0.3
      }
    }
]

I'm trying to come up with an expression that would return only 0.1 and 0.3. Is this possible? The JSON is stored as JSONB field in a PostgreSQL database, if that makes any difference.

A JSONPath expression along the lines of $.**.value could do that.

You could use .** JSONPath accessor in a jsonb_path_query() and make sure you're only catching values of .type()=="number" using a ?() filter expression:
demo at db<>fiddle
select id,jsonb_path_query(jdata,'strict $.**.value ? (@.type() == "number")')
from test;




id
jsonb_path_query




1
0.1


1
0.3



